# Capturing login name and using it in next activity

Tags: android

I have a login page; when I successfully login, the logged person's name should come on the next activity like so:

> Welcome xyz

How can I do that?

Comment: you need to post some code. Otherwise you are asking way too broad a question and we really can't help. Plus posting some code shows that you have in fact put some effort into this, instead of just asking for someone else's code.

Comment: Thanks Phil next time it wont happen.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this and always remember Phil's comment

**In Login Activity**

```
    String userName;
         if(login_ok){
        final Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Welcome.class);
        i.putExtras("userName",userName);//sending checked value to next activity
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

**in welcome Activity**

```
TextView view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String user=bundle.getString("userName"));
view1.setText("Welcome "+user);
```

Comment: ya I'll always remember next time what phil told me..thanks phil

Comment: Have look here.. it has example of both welcome screen & login http://androidsamples.blogspot.in/2009/06/how-to-use-http-connection-saxparser.html